# Notice: Undefined index: theme_settings in theme-settings.php

Tags: 7

I'm creating a custom theme settings and got error this two errors

- Notice: Undefined index: theme_settings in
  cocoa_form_system_theme_settings_alter() (line 411 of
  F:\DEV\SITES\DEV\cocoa\sites\all\themes\cocoa\theme-settings.php).
- Notice: Undefined index: favicon in
  cocoa_form_system_theme_settings_alter() (line 413 of
  F:\DEV\SITES\DEV\cocoa\sites\all\themes\cocoa\theme-settings.php).

[image: Error Screenshot]

[Here is my theme-settings.php](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6657587/theme-settings.php)

What am i missing. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you're seeing on site are notices. And those are coming because the index '`theme_settings`' and '`favicon`' doesn't exists in `$form` array. To fix this notice you can update the code as below:

```
  $form['cocoa_options']['drupal_settings']['theme_settings'] = $form['theme_settings'];
  // Change above line to below line.    
  $form['cocoa_options']['drupal_settings']['theme_settings'] = (!empty($form['theme_settings']) ? $form['theme_settings'] : '');

  $form['cocoa_options']['drupal_settings']['favicon'] = $form['favicon'];
  // Change above line to below line.
  $form['cocoa_options']['drupal_settings']['favicon'] = (!empty($form['favicon']) ? $form['favicon'] : '[DEFAULT_FAVICON_URL]');
```

More information on how to fix this can be found on [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/377342)